# Removing the Last Node of a Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is, my code compiles and runs past the problematic function shown below, but when I attempt to display the contents of all the nodes, I get this:

Unhandled exception at 0x50CE1F98 (msvcp100d.dll) in LinkedList.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEEE.

```
//remove (and cleanup after) the node at the tail of the LinkedList (pHead)
//return a pointer to the head node
ListNode* removeEnd( ListNode* pHead )
{
    ListNode* pCurr = pHead;
    ListNode* pPrevPtr = NULL;

    while (pCurr->pNextNode != NULL)
    {
        pCurr = pCurr->pNextNode;
        pPrevPtr = pCurr->pNextNode;
    }


    pPrevPtr = NULL;

    delete pCurr;

    return pHead;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to be:

```
while (pCurr->pNextNode != NULL)
{
    pPrevPtr = pCurr;
    pCurr = pCurr->pNextNode;
}
```

1. Loop until your pCurr reaches the end (i.e. next node is NULL)
2. The pPrevPtr becomes your new tail
3. Set pPrevPtr next to NULL (dereference old tail)

Answer (score 0):

I think that should be:

```
pPrevPtr = pCurr;
pCurr = pCurr->pNextNode;
```

Don't forget to unlink it.  Simply setting `pPrevPtr` to NULL afterwards will not affect your list.  You probably want:

```
if (pPrevPtr) pPrevPtr->pNextNode = NULL;
```

Comment: why unlink? OP only wants to delete last one, there is no mention about unlinking

Comment: @lizusek it is very likely they just forgot to mention this

Comment: @lizusek Why on earth would you delete the node and then leave a pointer to it in the list?  That is asking for so much trouble, I'm surprised by your comment.

Comment: Ah, it is OK, I thought you meant unlinking all nodes

Comment: @lizusek Oh, I see how you might have thought that.  Because I did not show the actual loop code, and then I mentioned something that happens after the loop.  Fair enough =)

Answer (score 0):

```
while (pCurr->pNextNode != NULL)
{
    pPrevPtr = pCurr;
    pCurr = pCurr->pNextNode;
}
```

Also, why do you return `pHead`? It is argument to function and is returned unchanged. Obviously you should also unlink deleted node.

```
delete pCurr;
if ( pPrevPtr ) pPrevPtr->pNextNode = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several bugs. For example pHead can be equal to NULL or you incorrectly set pPrevPtr here pPrevPtr = pCurr->pNextNode;  and here pPrevPtr = NULL;

Try the following code.

```
ListNode* removeEnd( ListNode* pHead )
{
    if ( pHead )
    {
       ListNode* pCurr = pHead;
       ListNode* pPrevPtr = NULL;

       while ( pCurr->pNextNode != NULL)
       {
          pPrevPtr = pCurr;
          pCurr = pCurr->pNextNode;
       }

       delete pCurr;
       if ( pPrevPtr ) pPrevPtr->pNextNode = NULL;
       else pHead = pPrevPtr; 
    }    

    return pHead;
}
```